# using facebook login & integrate with website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am almost about to finish this. I have taken code from aspsnippets. Just added some of my code to check the conditions. There are two buttons One do login from facebook & fetch information which is working Then on second button click it checks whether userid(got from fb) is exist in my db or not? If not then Insert it in db. But at the end of execution I am getting this exception

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Suraj\Desktop\fbLoginTest\login.aspx.vb:line 43

UPDATED

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblId.Text) Then
        Dim query As String = "Select ID, email From users where ID=@id"
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblId.Text)
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            'Do Login Code here
            Try
                Dim str As String = "select * from users where ID='" + lblId.Text + "';"
                Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                con.Open()
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2)

                Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
                Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
                con.Close()
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO users (ID, DP, displayName) values('" + lblId.Text + "', '" + ProfileImage.ImageUrl.ToString + "', '" + lblName.Text + "')"
                Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
                Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                Dim command As New MySqlCommand
                command.CommandText = str1
                command.Connection = con
                adapter.SelectCommand = command
                str2 = command.ExecuteReader
                command.Dispose()
                con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You already opened the connection with:

    `Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Data Source="server";port=3306;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=user;password=password;")
    con.Open()`

So, remove the con.Open() calls from within your try..catch clauses.

Comment: I have modified my code little still got error. Please see updated post & Error above.

Comment: Can you just look at my code once again. I update but still problem not solved